# jQuery UI - Changing Source to MySQL Data

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to create several autocomplete fields in a web page. I have 2 working, one using a local array as the source and another using a page called search.php but the one using search.php is not working.

Here is the code for the basic page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Remote datasource</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="../../jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../demos.css">
    <style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading { background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat; }
    </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">

 $(function() {

      var availableTags = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby", "python", "c", "scala", "groovy", "haskell", "perl"];

      $("#tags").autocomplete({

          source: availableTags

      });

  });


 $(function() {

      var availableTags = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby", "python", "c", "scala", "groovy", "haskell", "perl"];

      $("#tags2").autocomplete({

          source: "search2.php",
          minLength: 3

      });

  });


  </script>



  <input id="tags" />

  <input id="tags2" />




</body>
</html>
```

And here is the search.php page code

```
<?php

    // PHP5 Implementation - uses MySQLi.
    // mysqli('localhost', 'yourUsername', 'yourPassword', 'yourDatabase');
    $db = new mysqli(localhost', 'username' ,'password', 'database_name');

    if(!$db) {
        // Show error if we cannot connect.
        echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to the database.';
    } 


$term = $_GET['term'];   

$result = $db->query("SELECT registeredName FROM names WHERE registeredName LIKE '%".$term."%' ");


$array = array();   

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))   
{   
    $row_array['id'] = $data['id'];   
    $row_array['value'] = "$data[value]";   

    array_push($array, $row_array);   
}   

echo json_encode($array); 


?>
```

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Staggan,

In the php file, you're making a multi-dimensional array consisting of both the id and value from your db table.  In the autocomplete above where you're referencing the array that is hard coded, its single-dimensional (single-column) which leads me to believe that the autocomplete may not be able to deal with the multi-dimensional array in the second case.

Try taking (just comment out the line) the id column out of the array in the php assignment and just populate with the value (which I assume is where the real autocomplete potentials rest) and pass back that array.

See if that helps.

Ross

Update - Staggan - the code:

```
$row_array['value'] = "$data[value]";
```

should be:
    $row_array['value'] = $data['value'];

My guess is the PHP is giving you an error which you can view in you error_log for httpd and that your error_reporting level is such that its returning nothing in the json and hence not populating the autocomplete array for you.  Change this and let me know.

R

Comment: Staggan - also in your php where you assign the row_array['value'] - this php is wrong.  See above for what it should be..

Comment: on a side note - you should use mysqli or PDO to make that db query parameterized so that it won't get sql injected by a hacker if this is going to be on a public facing machine.  You should also do input validation the $_GET parameter as well before you use it to form the query.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help.. What I did was add 

$result2 = $result ->fetch_object(); 

mail ("xxxx" , "TERM" , print_r ($result2,1) );

Which emailed me at least one element from the MySQL Result

So I know the result is getting some data but populating the response does not appear to be working....

Comment: Finally solved it!

The MySQL query was returning a StdClass Object and not an array... so in the end I had to use:

while ($data = $result ->fetch_object()){        
  $row_array['id'] = $data->id;        
  $row_array['value'] = $data->Value;         
  
  array_push($array, $row_array);    
  }


This worked...

Now, I also want to be able to call the search page with an additional parameter so I can use this same function on multiple fields....

Any suggestions?

Thanks